# resource file in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, embedded-resource

I'm trying to understand an example in PyQt4 (simpletreemodel.pyw)
I see the code

```
import simpletreemodel_rc
```

But I can't see where the module is used in the example code
When I examine the module simpletreemodel, I see:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore

qt_resource_data = b"\
\x00\x00\x07\xb9\
\x47\
\x65\x74\x74\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x53\x74\x61\x72\x74\x65\x64\x09\x09\
\x09\x09\x48\x6f\x77\x20\x74\x6f\x20\x66\x61\x6d\x69\x6c\x69\x61\
\x72\x69\x7a\x65\x20\x79\x6f\x75\x72\x73\x65\x6c\x66\x20\x77\x69\
\x74\x68\x20\x51\x74\x20\x44\x65\x73\x69\x67\x6e\x65\x72\x0a\x20\
\x20\x20\x20\x4c\x61\x75\x6e\x63\x68\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x44\x65\x73\
\x69\x67\x6e\x65\x72\x09\x09\x09\x52\x75\x6e\x6e\x69\x6e\x67\x20\
\x74\x68\x65\x20\x51\x74\x20\x44\x65\x73\x69\x67\x6e\x65\x72\x20\
```

What this module is supposed to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you see is the byte-by-byte dump of the resources the `.qrc` file contains. You don't explicitly access the objects inside the module. Just import it, and you will be able to access those resources by their original names(and paths) but preceded by a colon.

```
pixmap = QPixMap(':/images/filename.jpg')
```

**UPDATE**:
QRC file is an XML file that looks like below:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/images">
    <file alias='filename.jpg'>images/filename.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then to generate it, use:

```
pyrcc4 -o images_rc.py images.qrc
```

Comment: Is the module generated automatically by Python? and how to create the qrc file?

Comment: But can you explain why we need to generate the images_rc.py instead of using directly the image file? Is it a performance optimization?

Comment: Its optional. Its like we are 'embedding' the image bytes in the application itself, rather than reading from the disk.