# Error while using pyrcc5

Tags: python, qt, resources, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a resource file for the GUI i'm creating with PyQt 5.

I've used the command line

```
pyrcc5 -o image_rc.py D:\MyFolder\resource_file.qrc
```

but i get an error message : *No resources in resource description*

This is how my resource file looks :

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file alias="img">Images\mypic.png</file>
    </qresource>

</RCC>
```

I've followed this topic : [python 3 how to put pics inside my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047692/python-3-how-to-put-pics-inside-my-program/30088121#30088121) but i somehow have something wrong.

**QUESTION** : if i understand, when you have a resource file, you still need to have the images in a folder somewhere. So why bother making a resource file then ? Isn't the same ? The images can still be deleted or moved no ?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951608/resource-file-in-pyqt4)

Comment: @Vaulstein yeah i saw that one too but i'm using PyQt5, not 4 and the thing is I can't even generate the .py file containing the resource

Comment: The qrc file is invalid because the `qresource` tag is unclosed.

Comment: The resources are all compiled into a single python module which can be imported at runtime. So when the application is installed, the image files are longer needed.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ok thanks. So I don't need the pictures once the resource file is created, which btw is still not working (even with qresource tag being closed)

Comment: @guy16. What does "still not working" mean?

Comment: @ekhumoro i stil have the same message error

Comment: @guy16. Works fine for me. Try using: `Images/mypic.png` (i.e. don't use backslashes).

Comment: @ekhumoro i tried it, same result

Answer (score 4):

For anyone facing this issue in the future, here is how I solved it.

find the following batch file :  pyuic5.bat

Which is a batch file, Edit it to add your own .ui file:

```
@"C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python" -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 Design.ui -o Design.py

pause
```

---

Hit enter in the CMD, then the "Design.py" will be created in the folder.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem. In your case you should change your command to:

`pyrcc5 D:\MyFolder\resource_file.qrc -o D:\MyFolder\resource_file.qrc_rc.py`

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into something similar with the new pyside2-rcc implementation.  In my case the .qrc file I was using had the normal XML declaration line at the top ('<?xml version="1.0" ?>').

Once I removed the XML declaration it started working perfectly.  So my qrc file now has '<RCC version="1.0">' as the very first line.

Maybe your "<!DOCTYPE RCC>" line is/was causing something similar?

Figured I'd throw this out there in case anyone else runs into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you  want to add an image to your interface by using stylesheet in Qwidget, anyway you can avoid this problem for add an image by using pixmap ->choose file

Answer (score 0):

I tried many methods, but it didn't work. Finally, I put the file in the project directory and it compiled successfully