# How to import resource file in PyQt and build with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

First of all, I have use Qt Designer to turn a picture into a .qrc file, Then I use pyrcc4 to turn this .qrc file into a .py resource.

`pyrcc4 qrcfile.qrc -o  pyfile.py`

then import this .py file in my .py file.
but after build with pyinstaller this resouce file does not work.

`pyinstaller -F my_code.py`

How to import resource file in PyQt and build with pyinstaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951608/resource-file-in-pyqt4)

QRC file is an XML file that looks like below:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/images">
    <file alias='filename.jpg'>images/filename.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

use it in .py file should be like this:

```
pixmap = QPixMap(':/images/filename.jpg')
```