# PyQt: How do resource files work?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I just started creating GUI's in PyQt and I wanted to add `pixmap` as a background on buttons, as icons etc.

And I have these questions:

1. If I ever compile `.py` to `.exe`, how can I include folders with resource files and images in it?
2. How can I import resource files in code? For example, I have a resource file, `Test.png`, how can I call it?

   class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

   ```
   def __init__(self):
       super(Window, self).__init__()
       self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
       self.setWindowTitle("Window")
       self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Test.png')) # < How can I import resource file here?
   ```
3. How can I generate resource files?
4. If resource files and pictures are in same folder, do I still need to specify full path?
5. What do I need, To organize Python code for a good application? (Do I need something other than resource file or Python code?)
6. Why are they so useful? Do I still need the original picture when I generate a resource file, or does it compile every pixel as useful code?

Comment: I suppose you need answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951608/resource-file-in-pyqt4

Comment: This is a lot more than one question: pretty much like a request for a tutorial, which is not really appropriate for Stack Overflow. I recommend breaking it up into single questions, and more thoroughly research each one, because some are already answered, so you won't need to ask them again. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22517901/1886357

Comment: Thanks and sorry for making this, But how can i import resource file in pyqt code? without using qt designer.